# Magnetic energy expression in frequency domain

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields

I have a question concerning the integral expression of the magnetic energy in frequency domain, I sometimes find this expression:

$$ E_m = \tfrac12 \int_V \bar{\mathbf H}\cdot\bar{\mathbf B} ^* dV $$

Other times, I stumble across the same expression but there is no conjugate:

$$ E_m = \tfrac12 \int_V \bar{\mathbf H}\cdot\bar{\mathbf B}~ dV $$

I am confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I drop the $\\bar$ sign because I think by it you mean just "vector" and it is already bolded, and use the $\\hat$ sign to signify an amplitude of the sinusoidal time varying vector.)

The two integrals mean different things. The real or imaginary part of
$$ \mathcal E_{1m} = \frac14 \int_V \hat{\mathbf H}\cdot\hat{\mathbf B} ^* dV ,$$ that is
$$ \mathcal E_r =\Re [\mathcal E_{1m}] = \Re{\left[\frac14 \int_V \hat{\mathbf H}\cdot\hat{\mathbf B} ^* dV \right]}\\
\mathcal E_i =\Im[\mathcal E_{1m}]= \Im{\left[\frac14 \int_V \hat{\mathbf H}\cdot \hat{\mathbf B} ^* dV \right]}$$ are *time averages* of the product of the sinusoidal varying fields $\mathbf H(t) = \Re[\hat {\mathbf {H}}e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}]$ and $\mathbf B(t) = \Re[\hat {\mathbf {B}}e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}]$.

This can be seen as follows. Let:
$$\mathcal E_{0m}(t) = \frac12 \int_V \Re[\hat {\mathbf {H}}e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}]\cdot\Re[\hat {\mathbf {B}}e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}]  dV\\
=\frac12 \left( \frac12 \int_V  [\hat {\mathbf {H}}e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}+\hat {\mathbf {H}^*}e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t}]\cdot [\hat {\mathbf {B}}e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}+\hat {\mathbf {B}^*}e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t}]  \right)dV\\
=\frac12 \left( \frac14 \int_V  [\hat {\mathbf {H}}\cdot \hat {\mathbf {B}} e^{\mathfrak j 2\omega t}
+\hat {\mathbf {H}}\cdot \hat {\mathbf {B}^*}
+\hat {\mathbf {H}^*}\cdot \hat {\mathbf {B}}
+\hat {\mathbf {H}^*}\cdot \hat {\mathbf {B}^*}e^{-\mathfrak j 2\omega t}]  \right)dV$$

Now take the time average o this integral over a *long* time, that is let $\omega T \gg 1$ and calculate
$$\langle \mathcal E_{0m}(t) \rangle = \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_{\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}\mathcal E_{0m}(t) dt $$

The second harmonic terms go to zero, and the result is

$$\langle \mathcal E_{0m}(t) \rangle = \frac18 \int_V  [\hat {\mathbf {H}^*}\cdot \hat {\mathbf {B}}+\hat {\mathbf {H}}\cdot \hat {\mathbf {B}^*}]dV$$
or
$$\langle \mathcal E_{0m}(t) \rangle =\frac14 \Re \left[ \int_V  \hat {\mathbf H} \cdot {\hat {\mathbf B}}^*\right]dV$$

Notice the $\frac14$ not $\frac12$ in front of the integral. Sometimes by *amplitude* the rms value $\hat {\mathbf H}_{rms}$ is meant, in which case $\hat {\mathbf H}_{rms}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\hat {\mathbf H}$ and then

$$\langle \mathcal E_{0m}(t) \rangle =\frac12 \Re \left[ \int_V  \hat {\mathbf H}_{rms} \cdot {\hat {\mathbf B}}_{rms}^*
\right]dV$$

Comment: the bar implied that the quantity is a phasor, so that I can evaluate the energy in frequency domain. The idea is to use this energy to compute the inductance at multiple frequencies. In order to explain it in the report I find myself confused with the different expressions..

Answer (score 1):

If you are going incredibly strictly in the Maxwellian theory, you will find that, actually, you can express all the physical quantities with real valued fields. In that case the conjugate is not needed.

However, there are plenty of situations whereby using complex numbers simplify the calculations way too much, and so it is helpful to put in the conjugates here and there, to help us get the calculations correct when we do choose to use complex numbers.

I will try my best to avoid telling you that going into talking about the energy in EM field and especially with materials is a slaughterhouse...